# MongoError: not authorized on sails to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 machine which has mongo running. I'm getting following error when I've tried to connect from another ec2 machine

```
MongoError: not authorized on sails to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }
  at Function.MongoError.create (/home/ec2-user/backstage/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
  at queryCallback (/home/ec2-user/backstage/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:281:36)
  at Callbacks.emit (/home/ec2-user/backstage/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
  at Connection.messageHandler (/home/ec2-user/backstage/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:249:23)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/backstage/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:265:22)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

My sails db has following user:

```
{
    "_id" : "sails.backstageadmin",
    "user" : "backstageadmin",
    "db" : "sails",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbAdmin",
            "db" : "sails"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "sails"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution yet ?

Comment: @molecule as far as I remember, I have overcome it to build something new from scratch (as I can afford  that luxury on my situation)